# Unable to convert object back into System.web.webpages.HelperResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am using the below code to render page and store the output in cache. so that in next request the page comes from cache (to reduce the processing time)

```
 HelperResult renderPageResult = null;
        try
        {
            if (objCache.Get(new CacheService().GetKey(cacheKey, _userContext)) == null)
            {
                renderPageResult = RenderPage(path, data);
                objCache.Add(new CacheService().GetKey(cacheKey, _userContext), renderPageResult);
            }
            else
            {
                renderPageResult = objCache.Get<HelperResult>(new CacheService().GetKey(cacheKey, _userContext));
            }

            return renderPageResult;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
```

When converting the object back to HelperResult I am getting not getting the HTML string and on UI getting the below exception

Value does not fall within the expected range.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: There is no exception but rather than html string I am getting is object

Comment: If I am understanding your question properly `objCache.Get` method returns object instead of object of class `HelperResult`. And when you are trying to render it in the UI you are seeing exception. Correct me if I am wrong? Can you provide some more context around what you are trying to achieve and where are you using the object of `HelperResult` ?

Comment: If there are few RenderPage in layout. I don't want to render them again and again. I want them to be rendered only once and store the output in cache Next time when there is request Renderpage won't be called and output is sent to layout page from Cache

Comment: So how are you trying to render the HelperResult retrieved from cache?

Comment: @Partial("~/Views/Partials/Shared/Footer.cshtml","footer", null) It works fine for first time but not with cache if you see the if condition

Comment: http://joonhachu.blogspot.sg/2012/03/aspnet-web-matrix-caching.html this might give you some hint

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the below code

```
return new HelperResult
              (
                  writer =>
                  {
                      writer.Write(renderPageContent);
                  }
              );
```